# Would there be any way to produce a force that follows a sinosoidal law?

Tags: science-based

What would produce a force that depends on the sine or cosine of the distance?

Comment: try physics stack exchange... also are you looking for a force that push and pull object repetitively?

Comment: In other words, a force where $F\propto\sin r$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. A simple pendulum has a force proportional to $\sin \theta$, although a small-angle approximation is generally used, wherein $\theta$ is used instead. One might object that $\theta$ is not a length. I suspect that a "truly" sinusoidal force dependent on linear Euclidean distance might be difficult.

Comment: I recall a type of cam that makes a pendulum work exactly with θ rather than just being a small-angle approximation.  Depending on what the OP means, perhaps a cam can do whatever is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Any standing wave will do the trick.

Comment: A standing wave depends on more than just the distance.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:  A pendulum will have a force based on the tilt, which is related to the sin of the angle.  Allow a weight to work in the manner.  Then, using [mechanical computing principles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s1i-dnAH9Y4), arrange for a light-weight cursor to ride in a track that moves horizontally only, in a straight line.  The weight rises behind the front panel, and the visible cursor shows the horizontal component only.

When you move the cursor, using a hand-held spring to tug it along the track, you will measure the restoring force to be proportional to the sin of the distance where full extension on the track is 1 unit.